# on using rxjs to update props of a react functional stateless component

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, observable, rxjs5, stateless

I thought I could use an observable to send in new props every second and have a react (functional, stateless) component thereby update itself. I am not sure what I am missing here. Here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kifagew/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
const propsObs = Rx.Observable.from(['Butler', 'Fritz', 'Dusty', 'Petey'])
const inte = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(4)
var props={olddog:'Rusty'}
const propsOverTime = propsObs.zip(inte, (aprop,intx)=>aprop) 
propsOverTime.subscribe((x)=>{
  props={...props, olddog:x}
  console.log(props)
})

const App = (props) =>{
  console.log(props.olddog)
  const getDog=()=>props.olddog
  const thedog = getDog()
  return(
    <div><h4>hello {thedog}</h4></div>)
}
ReactDOM.render(<App {...props}/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

The Observable changes props every second, each time creating a new props object. Shouldn't that be enough to force a re-render of the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional React component is just that.. a function. It's not "watching" its own props for changes. Something upstream must call your function to get new JSX. If you have an enclosing component that extends `React.Component` then you can call `setState` and pass in new props, or in your case, simply call `ReactDOM.render` with your updated JSX.

```
const App = props => {
  const getDog = () => props.olddog
  const thedog = getDog()
  return(
    <div><h4>hello {thedog}</h4></div>
  )
}

propsOverTime.subscribe(x => {
  props = {...props, olddog: x}
  ReactDOM.render(<App {...props}/>, document.getElementById('app'))
})
```